# "Pair" or "couple"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, word-usage

Can anyone tell me the difference between pairs or couples?

Especially I need to know if you say "a pair of puffins" or "a couple of puffins" if you mean a female and male bird.

Comment: Technically, a *pair* just means two birds, not even a male and a female. See [this article](http://www.cockatiels.org/main/articles/breeding-cockatiels/cockatiel-breeding-basics/pairs-bonded-proven-or-what/) for more precise terminology related to birds, specifically cockatiels.

Comment: Is this a married couple, or just two random birds hanging out?

Comment: @JLG my understanding is quite the opposite. A pair is matched but a couple is just two random penguins. Of course a couple plain and simple is two people going out.

Comment: @Mitch, I didn't comment on the word *couple* at all because I don't think it usually applies to birds. Yes, a couple would also mean two birds, not necessarily mates.

Comment: Thank you. I've especially wanted to know what to call two puffins.

Comment: *Brace* is also used for two birds, although moreso if they're destined for the table.

Comment: @Stuart F And lessso if they're not?

Comment: 'A couple of ...' means 2 [of], sometimes used fuzzily ("I'll be a couple of ticks"). But 'a couple' without context defaults to a married {human sense} couple. 'A couple of puffins' is thus merely two puffins, in some way associated (on the same ledge? seen by DA on the same boat trip?) // 'A pair of ...' speaks of 2 items in rather closer association – pair of earrings / stockings / aces / six-shooters / ... –  or a duplex – a pair of shorts / glasses .... 'A pair of puffins' is more stipulative than 'a couple of puffins', but still does not entail that they are a mated pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual term for a male and female bond is a *pair* not couple.

Speaking casually, "I saw a pair/couple of puffins the other day" would mean you'd seen two birds, of either sex.

As a verb, birds are said *to pair*, meaning male and female bonding for the purpose of rearing chicks. But *to couple* means to engage in sexual intercourse.

Comment: If they have been verified as mates, they're called a _mated pair_.

Comment: Opinion without support.

Comment: For birds, 'a pair' implies bonding, while it's 'a couple' for humans. However, 'A pair of sparrows' would be at least slightly unusual, probably implying they were together if not a bonded pair, while 'a couple of sparrows' is totally idiomatic. This just means two sparrows. 'We recorded a couple of sparrows and over a hundred pigeons during the day.'

Answer (score 3):

In my experience *pair of* means 2 and *couple of* means 2 or more.

> A pair of puffins

This would be 2 puffins.

> A couple of puffins

This would be 2 or a few (small number of) puffins.

What I think you want to say is a *puffin couple*.

Comment: Birds are said to develop [pair bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_bond). I don't think they would ever be called a *couple*. You could say they were a puffin [breeding pair.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeding_pair)

Comment: I used swans as my guide, who are also paired for life, although they are called both ```swan pair``` and ```swan couple``` the later is used more frequently. [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=swan+couple+swan+pair#q=swan%20couple%2C%20%20swan%20pair&cmpt=q)

Comment: How does *couple* mean "two *or more*"? It may be used *loosely* in that sense when spoken (and when intonation can convey the meaning), but I question whether it would normally be used in writing to mean "a few".

Comment: Merriam-Webster says _an indefinite small number_ [couple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couple)

Comment: Sure, the word _couple_ is often casually used to mean _a few_. As for Trevor's comment, I wonder, where does the O.P. specify that this is for formal writing? It could be a sixth grader talking about a trip to the zoo, in which case "I saw a couple of puffins" could refer to a male and female bird, or it could mean some arbitrarily small number of the birds.

Comment: The question is explicitly regarding [a couple of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/a+couple+of), and in this case couple mostly means _a few_ or _a small number of_, rarely does it mean a pairing bond.

Comment: Actually, I can't tell what this question is really about. The "Especially..." part of the O.P.'s question makes it hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In American, we typically use the term couple to identify things that are part of a relationship but not necessarily the same.

For example My wife and I are a married couple.
Just saying "They are a couple" implies that they are 2 people engaged in a romantic relationship.

Pair is usually used to describe single items with 2 parts such as a pair of scissors (with 2 blades) or a pair of pants (with 2 legs).

Where things get strange (for me at least) is that pair can also be used to describe things that are grouped because they are the same.
i.e A pair of jacks.

Answer (score 2):

A couple can mean two completely different components (eg. male and female humanbeings, or two different metals, say nickel and copper) together creating a new value, for instance a family or a thermocouple, a device that measures temperature, consisting of two metals with properties no single component represents.
A pair on the other hand represents two identical components: a pair of gloves, shoes, students (from the POV of their teacher they are the same)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is word order and context, not word choice. If you look at the definitions of both words at dictionary.com ([pair](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pair?s=t) and [couple](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/couple?s=t)), you'll find they actually use the other word in the definition. So instead of saying pair of, or couple of puffin, which could imply two non-related, you need to say a puffin pair or a puffin couple, which does imply relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the difference may keep you out of jail:

> Then we need more waiver of technicalities. In some states the escape
> from  punishment of men convicted of crime has been notably based upon
> the most absurd of technicalities. For example, one thief in Delaware
> escaped his just desserts [sic] because he was indicted for stealing a
> "pair" of shoes and it was proven that both shoes he took, by his own
> miscalculation, were "right"...

*[The New Jersey Law Journal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Jersey_Law_Journal/IWtKAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22his%20just%20desserts%22%20law&pg=PA137&printsec=frontcover)* (1913)

Answer (score 0):

“I saw a couple pairing” would seem a preliminary to “I saw a pair coupling” (and more suitable for family reading).

Comment: Interesting, but OP is obviously asking about the nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And not recently either. Sorry, I’m rather uncoupled from things.